# In Planetside 2 does activating your shield as Heavy Assault slow your movement speed?

Tags: planetside-2

I feel like I run slower when I activate my shield. Is this true?

Answer (score 3):

## It's supposed to

While I currently can't find data directly supporting this, according to [this bug report on the forums](http://forums.station.sony.com/ps2/index.php?threads/heavy-assault-shield-not-slowing-movement.81988/), it is supposed to slow you down.

Answer (score 3):

Activating your shield as Heavy Assault will slow you down. While I couldn't find any true hard data on movement speed, it is common knowledge that it slows you down when you activate it.

Here's some data on everything Heavy Assault Shield information:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao2sGqpRdtcDdEpSM1llZEtOU1BGSjVLaGQxMUJHNXc#gid=2